# Is there a constant-time (with preprocessing) algorithm for intersecting rounded rectangle with a polygon

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I need an algorithm to quickly determine wether given 2D polygon arbitrarily translated intersects given rounded rectangle.

We're given a polygon with N vertices and dimensions of the rounded rectangle (lenghts of sides and radius of corners).
We would like to answer many question of type does the polygon with translation (dx,dy) intersect the rounded rectangle.
We're allowed to do arbitrary precomputation on the polygon.

When radius of the corners rectangle is 0, there is trivial constant time algorithm - it's enough to compute an AABB of the polygon, and then in few comparisons check if, after translation, it intersects the rectangle.

When the radius is >0 the problem seems much harder. The fact that there seems to be potentially an infinite number of "bounding rounded rectangles" suggests that there is no constant-time algorithm that can check for the intersection.
But maybe I'm missing something.

Do you know by any change any sublinear algorithm for checking if a polygon intersects a rounded rectangle?

Comment: Constant time relative to what?

Comment: Checking the AABB of a polygon against a rectangle won't tell you if they intersect.

Comment: But what do you call arbitrarily translated ?? Any geometric enetity can intersect a rectangle if you allow arbitrary translation.

Comment: If I am right, intersection of a polygon with a rectangle and a rounded rectangle have the same asymptotic complexities.  But you can't check intersection of a polygon and a rectangle in constant time ! "A few comparisons" cannot be lower than O(N) comparisons, for an N-gon, in the worst case.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I believe he means that he knows in advance what the polygon shape is, just not its position. But I don't think there is any preprocessing one can do to take advantage of that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If preprocessing of the polygon is allowed, an efficient solution is possible:

- build the Minkowski sum of the polygon and rounded rectangle; this is a curvilinear polygon;
- every translation of the polygon wrt the rectangle corresponds to a point wrt the Minkowski sum;
- decompose the curvilinear polygon in slabs;
- you can perform location of an arbitrary point in that decomposition in time O(log(N)), and this is optimal.

Below, the sum of two polygons and of a concave polygon with a disk (the loop must be excluded). This generalizes to a rounded rectangle.

[image]

[image]

To locate a point, you identify the containing slab by dichotomic search. Then inside a slab, you can identify the containing curvilinear trapezoid (delimited by line segments or circular arcs) by a second dichotomic search.

[image]

---

If you have few polygons, with a simple shape, you can do the preprocessing by hand. Otherwise, the Minkowski sum and slab decomposition are a little painful.

Answer (score 1):

Let `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` be the coordinates of the AABB of the rounded rectangle, with `x1 < x2` and `y1 < y2`, and let `R` be the radius (of the quarter-circles).

Here is how I would handle the collision detection. Optionally, you can of course check for collision with the AABBs of both objects first, to reject early. Then, for each line in the polygon:

- check for intersection with the rectangle made from the following points:
  `(x1, y1+R)`, `(x1, y2-R)`, `(x2, y1+R)`, `(x2, y2-R)`
- check for intersection with the rectangle made from the following points:
  `(x1+R, y1)`, `(x1+R, y2)`, `(x2-R, y1)`, `(x2-R, y2)`
- check for intersection with each of the circles in the corners, that is the circles or radius R and centers:
  `(x1+R, y1+R)`, `(x1+R, y2-R)`, `(x2-R, y1+R)`, `(x2-R, y2-R)`

If any of these three checks gives an intersection, then the polygon intersects the rounded rectangle or is completely inside. Of course, you can check whether a point of the polygon is outside the rounded rectangle using the same method (you can easily do it at the same time as the intersection checks). Because a rounded rectangle is a convex shape, this is sufficient to say that the polygon is not completely inside.

That's O(N) where N is the number of sides of your polygon. If that's the complexity you are thinking of when you say "constant-time", then I don't believe there is any kind of preprocessing that can help go below O(N) in the general case.

Comment: If preprocessing is allowed, checking if the two shapes intersect is equivalent to checking if a point belongs to the Minkowski sum of the shapes. That sum is a curvilinear polygon. After a decomposition in (curvilinear) slabs, point queries can be performed in time O(Log(N)).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Very interesting. OP will need to clarify whether the shapes of both the polygon and the rounded rectangle are known beforehand (so the only variable is their relative position).

Comment: @Nelfeal , sorry about question being unclear. I've expanded it a bit. Yes, the polygon and rectangle are given beforehand, and the only variable is the translation of the polygon in 2D space.